# How to convert class with static items to module file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

I have a class like this:

```
export default class {
  static myConnection = GHD.initConnection();

  static getCards = () => this.myConnection.getCards();
}
```

And I call it as:

```
import connector from '../path.js';
connector.getCards();
```

I would like to convert this class with static items to module basically I don't want to use class.
Is this possible?
I tried something like:

```
module.exports {
  myConnection: GHD.initConnection();

  getCards: () => this.myConnection.getCards();
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Update with real code values requested in comments:

```
export default class {
  static firebaseReference = RNFirebase.initializeApp();

  static getDatabase = () => this.firebaseReference.database();

  static getUser = () => this.firebaseReference.auth().currentUser;
}
```

Comment: Why did you switch back to commonjs module syntax?!

Comment: First this was just file with export of `myConnection` then I switched to class, and realised that I don't need instance as this file only keep list of connections to different urls, databases etc. And now I don't know does it make sense to be class so I wanted to put it back as a module but I want to keep same interface so I don't need to change all references.

Comment: I was referring to `module.exports` vs `default export`, not the `class` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
export const myConnection = GHD.initConnection();
export const getCards = () => myConnection.getCards();
```

then

```
import * as connector from '../path.js';
connector.getCards();
```

or

```
import { getCards } from '../path.js';
getCards();
```

If you must keep compatibility with the default import syntax, you can use

```
export const myConnection = GHD.initConnection();
export const getCards = () => myConnection.getCards();

/** @deprecated */
export default { myConnection, getCards };
```

Comment: Actually with this I am getting same problem. When I write code like this my connection is not initialised so I am getting undefined everywhere. Why class work and exports like this don't

Comment: @1110 Which "*the same problem*"? The last snippet in your question was a syntax error from the `module.exports {`, surely you don't get that again. No, the code in my answer is exactly equivalent to the `class` syntax.

Comment: Syntax is fine. In class example when I call `connector.getCards()` it work as `myConnection` has value but if I write it like you answered `myConnection` is `undefined`. This is what I don't understand why class initialised connection and equivalent of module doesn't.

Comment: @1110 It shouldn't be. Is this your actual code or did you simplify it? Can you post the entire module, please?

Comment: @1110 And where does `RNFirebase` come from?

Comment: It's a library from npm I ommited import

Comment: @1110 Yes. How many more things did you omit? There's nothing special about `firebaseReference`. Can you get the value after the variable is initialised?  But if you need further debugging help, I'd suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that, where you post the entire current code and the exact error message.

Comment: You have right. I created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457006/how-to-convert-class-with-static-member-to-module-with-exported-fields and accepted your answer as it answers this part of question. Thanks

Comment: Ah, the problem is with `this`, not with `myConnection`. If you write it in the style I suggested, you won't need to use `this` any more and it'll work.

Comment: And this two ways are equal it’s only syntatic change right? Funttionalu they are same